# bookshelf.js not loading relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Im new to bookshelfjs and i want to get the data from other table using the ID from other table.
Im using this sample data:

```
/* User's Table */
----------------+-------------------+----------
   lastname     |    firstname      |   id  
----------------+-------------------+---------
Dela Cruz          Juan                1
Pendoku            Pedro               2

/* Logs's Table */
----------------+--------------+----------
     userid     |    time      |   id  
----------------+--------------+---------
  1                 8:00           1
  2                12:00           2
  1                 9:00           3
```

Question: how i can query the logs of specific user thru bookshelf.js?

so the result should be like this:

```
----------------+--------------+----------
     lastname   |    time      |   id  
----------------+--------------+---------
 Dela Cruz          8:00           1
 Dela Cruz          9:00           3
```

My query:

```
new User({'lastname': 'Dela Cruz'})
  .logs()
  .fetch()
  .then(function(timelog) {
    console.log(timelog.toJSON());
});
```

My models

```
var User, Log;

User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName:'user',
  logs: function() {
     return this.hasMany(Log, 'userid');
  }
});

Log = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName:'log',
  user: function(){
    return this.belongsTo(User, 'userid');
  }
});
```

Log Error:

```
{ __cid: '__cid1',
  method: 'select',
  options: undefined,
  bindings: [undefined],
  sql: 'select log.* from log where log.userid = ?'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the user model to this:

```
User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName:'user',
  logs: function() {
     return this.hasMany(Log);
  }
});
```

And try this

```
new User({'lastname': 'Dela Cruz'})
  .fetch({withRelated:['logs']})
  .then(function(timelog) {
    console.log(timelog.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: Tried this out myself (I was stuck someplace similar) and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the {idAttribute: 'UserId'} to your User model
I found mine was case sensitive to the FieldNames so 'userid' resulted in no returned data but 'UserId' did. So make sure it matches the field in your db

So change your model to

```
User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName:'user',
  idAttribute: 'userid',
  logs: function() {
     return this.hasMany(Log);
  }
});
```

And try the query as shown in uglycode's answer